# Why are my Git commits from a VM showing up as coming from a totally different person?

Tags: git, github

I was working in a new CentOS 7 VM today, as my normal environment was unavailable. I made the VM this morning for this express purpose. Upon pushing my project to a private repository on my own Github, I have found that the commits I made from this VM come up under an entirely different person; I have never heard of this person, and they've obviously never accessed my VM. What could this be? I'm pretty spooked.

Comment: Did you configure your git details in the vm?

Comment: Looks like the git config in that VM already has `user.name` and `user.email` set by that other person. git does not know (and does not care) that a new person (you) is using the VM, so you need to configure git `user.name` and `user.email` again.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `git config --show-origin -l`

If you see user.name/user.email in ~/.gitconfig, that would be a *global* setting applied by default to *all* repositories for the owner of the current account (accessing `~/.gitconfig`)

You can override that global setting by a *local* one, local to your own repository:

```
cd /path/to/my/cloned/repository
git config user.name me
git config user.email me@email.com
```

> as my normal environment was unavailable.

In your normal environment, you might not need to do that in each of your repositories, since your *global* settings would be tailored to your account.
But that is manifestly not the case in that new CentOS 7 VM.